# TCP connection stucked in SYNC_RECV stated

Tags: networking

I have two machines: edge1(10.22.46.11) and edge2(10.22.46.48), both of them are k8s worker nodes. On edge1 I tried to visit one service which has an endpoint located on edge2. I send request like this:

```
curl -m 5 host-edge-nginx
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5001 milliseconds\

bash-5.1# nslookup host-edge-nginx
Server:     169.254.25.10
Address:    169.254.25.10#53

Name:   host-edge-nginx.fabedge-e2e-test.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.233.52.186
```

The service host-edge-nginx-793's IP is 10.233.52.186, this IP is assigned to kube-ipvs0 on edge1. As you can see, the request was timeout. The tcpdump output:

```
[root@edge1 ~]# tcpdump -nn -i any port 80 or 30080
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
17:06:49.407148 IP 10.22.46.11.57104 > 10.22.46.48.30080: Flags [S], seq 1003993294, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 84142687 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:06:49.407481 IP 10.22.46.48.30080 > 10.22.46.11.57104: Flags [S.], seq 4067044182, ack 1003993295, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 197964760 ecr 84142687,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:06:50.407345 IP 10.22.46.11.57104 > 10.22.46.48.30080: Flags [S], seq 1003993294, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 84143688 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:06:50.407688 IP 10.22.46.48.30080 > 10.22.46.11.57104: Flags [S.], seq 4067044182, ack 1003993295, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 197965760 ecr 84142687,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:06:51.408815 IP 10.22.46.48.30080 > 10.22.46.11.57104: Flags [S.], seq 4067044182, ack 1003993295, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 197966762 ecr 84142687,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:06:52.411309 IP 10.22.46.11.57104 > 10.22.46.48.30080: Flags [S], seq 1003993294, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 84145692 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:06:52.411652 IP 10.22.46.48.30080 > 10.22.46.11.57104: Flags [S.], seq 4067044182, ack 1003993295, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 197967764 ecr 84142687,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:06:54.808781 IP 10.22.46.48.30080 > 10.22.46.11.57104: Flags [S.], seq 4067044182, ack 1003993295, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 197970162 ecr 84142687,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:06:58.808756 IP 10.22.46.48.30080 > 10.22.46.11.57104: Flags [S.], seq 4067044182, ack 1003993295, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 197974162 ecr 84142687,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

It seems the connection couldn't finish handshake, client side retransmitted syn packets again and again.

I used ss and netstat, but found nothing. Then I used conntrack and found this:

```
[root@edge1 ~]# conntrack -L | grep 30080
conntrack v1.4.4 (conntrack-tools): 17 flow entries have been shown.
tcp      6 59 SYN_RECV src=10.233.52.186 dst=10.233.52.186 sport=52626 dport=80 src=10.22.46.48 dst=10.22.46.11 sport=30080 dport=1147 mark=0 use=1
```

As you see, the connection was stucked on SYNC_RECV state. I guess the client didn't receive ACK packet, but I also used iptables trace:

```
[84771.535104] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3e:39:f6:2d:fa:16:3e:c8:8d:b2:08:00 SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.22.46.11 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=38970 SEQ=3634038526 ACK=1413810229 WINDOW=28960 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A0BD1B6490508ECD001030307) 
[84771.535121] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3e:39:f6:2d:fa:16:3e:c8:8d:b2:08:00 SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.22.46.11 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=38970 SEQ=3634038526 ACK=1413810229 WINDOW=28960 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A0BD1B6490508ECD001030307) 
[84771.535148] TRACE: mangle:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3e:39:f6:2d:fa:16:3e:c8:8d:b2:08:00 SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.233.52.186 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=52628 SEQ=3634038526 ACK=1413810229 WINDOW=28960 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A0BD1B6490508ECD001030307) 
[84771.535160] TRACE: filter:INPUT:rule:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3e:39:f6:2d:fa:16:3e:c8:8d:b2:08:00 SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.233.52.186 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=52628 SEQ=3634038526 ACK=1413810229 WINDOW=28960 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A0BD1B6490508ECD001030307) 
[84771.535175] TRACE: filter:KUBE-NODE-PORT:return:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3e:39:f6:2d:fa:16:3e:c8:8d:b2:08:00 SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.233.52.186 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=52628 SEQ=3634038526 ACK=1413810229 WINDOW=28960 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A0BD1B6490508ECD001030307) 
[84771.535186] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3e:39:f6:2d:fa:16:3e:c8:8d:b2:08:00 SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.233.52.186 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=52628 SEQ=3634038526 ACK=1413810229 WINDOW=28960 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A0BD1B6490508ECD001030307)
```

As you can see the ACK packet has pass through filter INPUT policy, which is ACCPT by default.

```
[root@edge1 ~]# iptables -t filter -S | grep INPUT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes health check rules" -j KUBE-NODE-PORT
```

So I think this means the ACK packet has been received by client side.

I was stucked here and have no more clue. Any help is welcome and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the ACK packet happened to match on xfrm policy and was dropped by xfrm.

Answer (score 0):

If you use externalTrafficPolicy:Local and proxy-mode=ipvs you may hit this https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93456#issuecomment-733069629

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The service is just a clusterIP service with an hostNetWork pod as endpoint, the traffic has been masqueraded, so I don't think it's releated to that issue.